# How to convert an String into Array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

In ruby, I have an array with an string value:

```
my_array=["210,207,203,199,169,165,159,152,148,144,140,137"]
```

How do I convert it into an normal array like this:

```
my_array=[210,207,203,199,169,165,159,152,148,144,140,137]
```

**Note: all the elements are non-negative values.**
I know I can do this by trim the double quote manually, but I am wondering if there is an more elegant way to implement this?

Comment: I assume that, as in your example, the integers you wish to extract are always non-negative, but that should should be stated. Also, I don't know what you mean by "trim the double-quotes manually".

Comment: DV Your title is really misleading. This is an array with a string in it. and converting to array of integers

Comment: Your title is really misleading. This is an array with a string in it. and converting to array of integers

Answer (score 10):

I think this should work:

```
my_array = my_array[0].split(',').map(&:to_i)
```

Comment: Understatement not needed. :-)

Answer (score 7):

Expanding davidrac's answer, you could also use [`String#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-scan) instead of [`String#split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-split):

```
my_array = my_array[0].scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)
```

**EDIT**

The benchmarks on this clear show that `String#scan` is slower:

```
require 'benchmark'
string = "210,207,203,199,169,165,159,152,148,144,140,137"
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report('split') { 1_000_000.times { string.split(',').map(&:to_i) } }
  x.report('scan') { 1_000_000.times { string.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i) } }
end
```

yields:

```
           user     system      total        real
split  3.550000   0.010000   3.560000 (  3.580334)
scan   7.350000   0.020000   7.370000 (  7.402508)
```

Comment: The benchmarks are very similar. Ran it three times. 1st time split won, 2nd time tie, 3rd time scan won. Test case was string from OP's example.

Comment: Fe (aka @Iron), what is the basis for your assertion?

Comment: @Cary it's a small difference, I'm sure, but the regex will likely be a heavier mechanism.

Comment: @Iron, I used to think of regex operations as being generally slow, but I've since seen some that have been lightning fast. Best to run benchmarks before drawing such conclusions.

Comment: @Cary, I would not disagree with that.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I've updated my answer to include benchmarks.